# Component won't refresh on attribute change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

My problem is, crud-table component isn't refreshing when i change `currentTable`. When i assign `currentTable = 'doctor'` at `created ()` or something. It works, but it isn't here. Why?

```
<template>
  <div id="adminpanel">
    <div id="tabs">
      <button
        v-for="tableName in tables"
        :key="tableName"
        @click="switchTo(tableName)"
        >{{ tableName }}
      </button>

      <crud-table :tableName="currentTable"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CrudTable from './CrudTable.vue'

export default {
  name: 'AdminPanel',
  data () {
    return {
      tables: ['user', 'doctor'],
      currentTable: 'user'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    switchTo: function (tableName) {
      this.currentTable = tableName
    }
  },
  components: {
    CrudTable
  }
}
</script>
```

Edit:
It's not a duplicate, because I didn't misspelled prop name in any way. And it works, when I set to different initial value.

This is my CrudTable component:

```
<template>
  <table id="crudtable">
      <tr>
        <th>Akcje</th>
        <th v-for="h in header" :key="h">
          {{ h }}
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="row in rows" :key="row.id">
        <td>
          <span class="action edit">E</span>
          <span @click="save(visible(row))" class="action save">S</span>
          <span class="action delete">D</span>
        </td>
        <td v-for="cell in ordered(visible(row))" :key="cell.name">
          <input v-model="cell.value" type="text"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</template>

<script>
import {HTTP} from '../http-common'
import {popUp} from '../utils'

export default {
  name: 'CrudTable',
  props: ['tableName'],
  data () {
    return {
      rows: [],
      header: [],
      chunkSize: 10
    }
  },
  computed: {
    endpoint: function () {
      return `/api/${this.tableName}`
    }
  },
  methods: {
    visible: function (row) {
      let ret = {}
      for (let prop in row) {
        if (!prop.startsWith('_')) {
          ret[prop] = row[prop]
        }
      }
      return ret
    },
    ordered: function (row) {
      let ret = []
      for (let col of this.header) {
        ret.push({name: col, value: row[col]})
      }
      return ret
    },
    fillTable: function () {
      let self = this
      let link = `${this.endpoint}/?page=0&size=100`
      HTTP.get(link)
        .then(function (response) {
          self.rows = response.data
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err.response)
        })
    },
    fillHeader: function () {
      let self = this
      HTTP.get(self.endpoint)
        .then(function (response) {
          self.header = Object.keys(response.data)
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err.response)
        })
    },
    save: function (row) {
      HTTP.patch(this.endpoint, row)
        .then(function (response) {
          popUp('ok', `Zapisano obiekt o id ${row.id}`)
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err.response)
        })
    }
  },
  beforeMount () {
    this.fillTable()
    this.fillHeader()
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: @Ginko What do you mean by "refresh"? Can you show the definition of `CrudTable` and how `tableName` is used there?

Comment: Here's a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/wy2ypyo5m5) of your code with a dummy `CrudTable`. That's why it's important to see your definition of `CrudTable`. :)

Comment: I edited it, could you look once again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're wondering why `CrudTable.fillTable()` is not invoked when there's a change in `CrudTable.endpoint` (which depends on `CrudTable.tableName`). The issue is `fillTable()` is just a method, which is not reactive. `fillTable()` evaluates `endpoint` only at the time of call.

If you want `fillTable()` to be called whenever `endpoint` changes, you'd need to add a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on that:

```
watch: {
  endpoint(value) { // <-- called when endpoint computed prop changes
    this.fillTable(value);
  }
},
methods: {
  fillTable(endpoint) {
     // http.get(`${endpoint}/users`)
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/wy2ypyo5m5)

Comment: I admire your knowledge, great wizard. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The likely problem is that you should be using...

```
<crud-table :table-name="currentTable"/>
```

instead of...

```
<crud-table :tableName="currentTable"/>
```

Properties have to be kabobcase as I recall.

Comment: That kebab-case limitation applies only to in-DOM templates, which is not the case here because the OP is using an SFC (transformed by `vue-loader` into a string template). See [Codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/gdxJbX?editors=1010).